# how to fix addEventListener is undefined using Jasmine and Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

So, here's my ongoing problem.

I have a ts file that contains a call to setting addEventListner which works just fine.

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.autoCompleteInput = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('.search-input');

    console.log('Add Event Listener: ', this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('blur', this.onBlur.bind(this)));

    console.log('Native Element: ', this.inputRef);

    document.addEventListener('onBlur', function(){
      console.log('I clicked on the doc somewhere');
    });

    this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('blur', () => {
      console.log('AddEventListener instantiated for BLUR');
    });

    this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
      console.log('AddEventListener instantiated for INPUT');
    });

    this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('focus', () => {
      console.log('AddEventListener instantiated for FOCUS');
    });

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.bindOnBlurStateEventCallback();
    this.bindOnInputStateEventCallback();
    this.bindOnFocusStateEventCallback();

    this.renderer.setAttribute(this.autoCompleteInput, 'aria-autocomplete', 'both');
    if (this.filter !== undefined && this.filter !== null && this.filter !== '') {
      this.filter = '';
    }

  }

  bindOnBlurStateEventCallback(): void {
    if (this.autoCompleteInput.value.length > 0) {
      console.log('You selected: ', this.autoCompleteInput.value);
    }
    const blurCallback = (message: string) => {
      console.log('Callback Message: ', message);
    }
    console.log('blurCallback ', blurCallback);
    this.bindingBlur();
  }

  bindingBlur(): string {
    console.log('Binding Blur called');
    this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('onBlur', () => {
      console.log('You selected: ', this.autoCompleteInput.value);
    });
    return this.autoCompleteInput.value;
  }

  bindOnInputStateEventCallback(): void {
    // this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('input', this.onInput.bind(this));
    this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('onInput', () => {
      console.log('You selected: ', this.inputRef.nativeElement.value);
    });
    this.bindingInput();
  }

  bindingInput(): string {
    console.log('Binding Input called');
    this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('onInput', () => {
      console.log('You selected: ', this.autoCompleteInput.value);
    });
    return this.autoCompleteInput.value;
  }

  bindOnFocusStateEventCallback(): void {
    this.inputRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('focus', this.onFocus.bind(this));
    this.inputRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('onFocus', () => {
      console.log('You selected: ', this.inputRef.nativeElement.value);
    });
    this.bindingFocus();
  }

  bindingFocus(): string {
    console.log('Binding Focus called');
    this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('onFocus', () => {
      console.log('You selected: ', this.autoCompleteInput.value);
    });
    return this.autoCompleteInput.value;
  }
```

in the spec.ts file I have this...

```
        beforeEach(async(() => {

            eventListenerService = jasmine.createSpyObj('onBlur', ['blur']);

            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
                imports: [
                    RouterTestingModule.withRoutes([])
                ],
                declarations: [
                    AutocompleteComponent
                ],
                providers: [AutocompleteComponent],
                schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
            }).compileComponents().then(() => {
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AutocompleteComponent);
                autoCompleteComponent = fixture.componentInstance;
                autocompleteInput = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('.search-input');
            });
        }));

        it('adds listener events', function () {
            spyOn(document, 'addEventListener').and.callThrough();
            spyOn(window, 'addEventListener').and.callThrough();

            expect(document.addEventListener.prototype).not.toBeTruthy;
            expect(window.addEventListener.prototype).not.toBeTruthy;
            
            expect(document.addEventListener.prototype).toBeTruthy;
            expect(window.addEventListener.prototype).toBeTruthy;
            //expect(autoCompleteComponent.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener.prototype).toBeTruthy;
        });

        it('should create the app', () => {
            const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AutocompleteComponent);
            const app = fixture.componentInstance;
            expect(app).toBeTruthy();
        });

        // beforeEach(function () {
        //     spyOn(autoCompleteComponent, "ngAfterViewInit").and.callThrough();
        // });

        it("when called multiple times ngOnInit() and fires all three callbacks in order", () => {

            spyOn(autoCompleteComponent, 'ngOnInit').and.callThrough();


            // document.addEventListener('blur', onblur);
            // spyOn(autoCompleteComponent.autoCompleteInput, 'addEventListener').and.callThrough;
            autoCompleteComponent.ngOnInit();

            spyOn(autoCompleteComponent, 'bindOnBlurStateEventCallback').and.callThrough();
            // autoCompleteComponent.bindOnBlurStateEventCallback();
            autoCompleteComponent.bindingBlur();
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.bindingBlur).toHaveBeenCalled();
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.bindOnBlurStateEventCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();

            spyOn(autoCompleteComponent, 'bindOnInputStateEventCallback').and.callFake(() => {
                autoCompleteComponent.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('input', autoCompleteComponent.onInput.bind(document));
            });
            // autoCompleteComponent.bindOnInputStateEventCallback();
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.bindOnInputStateEventCallback).toBeTruthy();
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.bindOnInputStateEventCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();

            spyOn(autoCompleteComponent, 'bindOnFocusStateEventCallback').and.callFake(() => {
                autoCompleteComponent.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('focus', autoCompleteComponent.onFocus.bind(document));
            });
            // autoCompleteComponent.bindOnFocusStateEventCallback();
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.bindOnFocusStateEventCallback).toBeTruthy();
            expect(autoCompleteComponent.bindOnFocusStateEventCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();

        });
```

the issue is addEventListner is ALWAYS undefined running the jasmine test

but when I run the app, my calls are working fine as evident in the console

```
blurCallback  ƒ (message) {
        console.log('Callback Message: ', message);
    }
component.ts:93 Binding Blur called
component.ts:109 Binding Input called
component.ts:125 Binding Focus called
```

The error Jasmine always shows is:

Chrome 90.0.4430 (Windows 10.0.0) Auto Complete Component should call bindingBlur  FAILED
TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined
at 
at **AutocompleteComponent.bindingBlur** (*karma_webpack*/src/app/autocomplete/autocomplete.component.ts:124:10)

Thoughts?

UPDATE for Owen to see what I "thought" worked.

Owen, so this is how I got around the problem:

1. moved the code BACK into AfterViewInit

   ngAfterViewInit() {

   ```
    this.autoCompleteInput = <HTMLInputElement>document.querySelector('.search-input');

    this.bindOnBlurStateEventCallback();
    this.bindOnInputStateEventCallback();
    this.bindOnFocusStateEventCallback();

    if (this.autoCompleteInput && this.autoCompleteInput.value.length > 0) {
      this.renderer.setAttribute(this.autoCompleteInput, 'aria-autocomplete', 'both');
      if (this.filter !== undefined && this.filter !== null && this.filter !== '') {
        this.filter = '';
      }
    }
   ```

   }
2. created these callbacks which work great... but as you'll see, I can now remove the addEventListener call which is now unnecessary.

   ```
    bindOnBlurStateEventCallback(): void {

      if (this.autoCompleteInput && this.autoCompleteInput.value.length > 0) {
        console.log('You selected: ', this.autoCompleteInput.value);
        const blurCallback = (message: string) => {
          console.log('Callback Message: ', message);
        }
        console.log('blurCallback ', blurCallback);
        this.bindingBlur();
      }

    }

    bindingBlur(): string {
      console.log('Binding Blur called');
      this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('blur', () => {
        console.log('You selected: ', this.autoCompleteInput.value);
      });
      return this.autoCompleteInput.value;
    }

    bindOnInputStateEventCallback(): void {
      if (this.autoCompleteInput && this.autoCompleteInput.value.length > 0) {
        this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('onInput', () => {
          console.log('You selected: ', this.inputRef.nativeElement.value);
        });
        this.bindingInput();
      }
    }

    bindingInput(): string {
      console.log('Binding Input called');
      this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('onInput', () => {
        console.log('You selected: ', this.autoCompleteInput.value);
      });
      return this.autoCompleteInput.value;
    }

    bindOnFocusStateEventCallback(): void {
      if (this.autoCompleteInput && this.autoCompleteInput.value.length > 0) {
        this.inputRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('focus', this.onFocus.bind(this));
        this.inputRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('onFocus', () => {
          console.log('You selected: ', this.inputRef.nativeElement.value);
        });
        this.bindingFocus();
      }
    }

    bindingFocus(): string {
      console.log('Binding Focus called');
      this.autoCompleteInput.addEventListener('onFocus', () => {
        console.log('You selected: ', this.autoCompleteInput.value);
      });
      return this.autoCompleteInput.value;
    }
   ```
3. implemented the (blur)=eventHandler(); but there was already something there, so I put a comma between it like so:

BEFORE

```
(blur)="updateAriaExpanded()"
```

AFTER

```
(blur)="updateAriaExpanded(), eventHandler()"
```

I've chained method calls before so this should work.

I'm going to clean up the code and implement your way and let you know and show you the cleaner business logic.

Comment: This works? `(blur)="updateAriaExpanded(), eventHandler()"`? Both event handlers are called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem Analysis

That is totally expected, consider below simple code illustration

```js
let p;

p.addEventListener('blur', () => {})

p = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
```

```html
<div id='myDiv'></div>
```

You are calling `addEventListener` on an element that is yet to exist.

Remember below,

1. Elements on the dom **DO NOT EXIST** in the `ngOnInit`
2. `ngOnInit` life cycle hooks is called before `ngAfterViewInit`

> I have a ts file that contains a call to setting `addEventListner` which works just fine.

I believe the problem starts in the above line. You are calling `addEventListner` on DOM element yet to exist which will definitely not work. Basically your test is working well and has helped in identifying a problem in your approach

### Solution

Move code to `ngAfterViewInit` life cycle hook

Let me begin by saying that I wouldn't do this.

When using Angular you shouldn't be adding event listener but binding to dom events. Instead of adding 'blur' event listener simply bind to `(blur)='eventHandler()'`. This has already been tested by Angular and works so you wouldn't need to test that event listeners were added but focus mainly on business logic rather than code functionality

Comment: Owen! Brilliant! Awesome! You Rock!  I was doing it the OLD FASHIONED way. I'll post what I came up with and show you how childish it was. I didn't think through the problem and was a slave to Jasmine. You've reduced it to the lowest common denominator and showed me the simplest method possible.  DM me as I'd love to talk more about what you know. THANK YOU SIR! Bravo Zulu!

Comment: Owen, take a look at how I did it BEFORE I saw your solution. Now I need to adapt your solution.  peter at webparity dot net